# Ansible: How to modify a list of dicts

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I want to modify dicts in a list within hostvars with a new entry for the IP address I get from the IPAM.

```
{
  "vm_guest_networks": [
    {
      "device_type": "vmxnet3",
      "state": "present",
      "subnet": "10.91.1.0/24"
    },
    {
      "device_type": "vmxnet3",
      "state": "present",
      "subnet": "10.91.0.0/24"
    }
  ]
}
```

Within a loop I have the subnet to identify the right dict and the IP address I want to add with the ipv4_address key so the result should look like:

```
{
  "vm_guest_networks": [
    {
      "device_type": "vmxnet3",
      "state": "present",
      "subnet": "10.91.1.0/24",
      "ipv4_address": "10.91.1.216"
    },
    {
      "device_type": "vmxnet3",
      "state": "present",
      "subnet": "10.91.0.0/24",
      "ipv4_address": "10.91.0.21"
    }
  ]
}
```

The current WIP ansible code is at https://pastebin.com/bFc1Ww2K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume the list of IPs is available. For example

```
ip4: [10.91.1.216, 10.91.0.21]
```

Let's use [combine](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) filter and [Extended loop variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables) to create a new list where each dictionary will be updated. For example

```
    - set_fact:
        mydata: "{{ mydata|default([]) +
                    [item|combine({'ipv4_address': ip4[ansible_loop.index0]})] }}"
      loop: "{{ vm_guest_networks }}"
      loop_control:
        extended: yes

    - set_fact:
        vm_guest_networks: "{{ mydata }}"
    - debug:
        var: vm_guest_networks
```

give

```
    "vm_guest_networks": [
        {
            "device_type": "vmxnet3", 
            "ipv4_address": "10.91.1.216", 
            "state": "present", 
            "subnet": "10.91.1.0/24"
        }, 
        {
            "device_type": "vmxnet3", 
            "ipv4_address": "10.91.0.21", 
            "state": "present", 
            "subnet": "10.91.0.0/24"
        }
    ]
```